# start sessions manually in laravel 8 without authentication

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8

Can session variables be created without first passing through Laravel authentication? My Laravel app does not require user authentication but I need to make use of session variables. Any ideas?

Comment: it's not about authentification, it's about the session service provider being initiated.

Comment: Please how do I initiate it?

Comment: it initiates by itself. Where are you trying to use it. add more details to your question. what did you try, the code you tried and the error you're getting.